# Emmet <p> then <span> then <p> content

Tags: emmet

I want to write this with emmet:

```
<p><span class="subtitle">Subtitle:</span> text after subtitle</p>
```

I've tried this:

```
 li>span.subtitle{Subtitle:}{ text}
 li>(span.subtitle{Subtitle:}){ text}
 li{ text}>span.subtitle{Subtitle:}
```

How to put the `<span>` first then the text inside the `<p>`?

Comment: See http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#text : `p>span.subtitle{Subtitle:}+{ text after subtitle}`

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok this works perfectly! Why not post it like an answer?

Comment: Because the very this behaviour is described in docs. Not sure if it’s the answer for common problem people stumble upon.